# Simple Objective-C Program Not Working

Tags: objective-c

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int n, number, triangularNumber;
    NSLog(@"What Triangular Number Do You Want?");
    scanf(@"%i", &number);
    triangularNumber = 0;

    for (n = 1; n <= number; ++n)  
        triangularNumber += n;
        NSLog(@"Triangular Number %i is %i", number, triangularNumber);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

The output when I write an integer is this:

```
Triangular Number 0 is 0
```

Comment: Since using number as pointer, reference it's value with *number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input number is 0, and your condition in the for loop starts at 1. Therefore, the loop is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
for (n = 1; n <= number; ++n)  {
        triangularNumber += n;
        NSLog(@"Triangular Number %i is %i", number, triangularNumber);
}
```

In the way you wrote it, it is parsed as:

```
for (n = 1; n <= number; ++n)  {
    triangularNumber += n;
}
NSLog(@"Triangular Number %i is %i", number, triangularNumber);
```

And since the input (number) is 0 (as indicated by the print) the loop doesn't happen, yet the line is printed.

Comment: The indentation on the code is misleading.  I don't think he means to log every intermediate value, just the final result.

Comment: yes but as i said in the scanf, whatever int i write should be assigned to number, so then number should have a value